# Gave up waiting for root device on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10, bios

I'm running a dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 with windows 10 laptop. While using the windows, after an automatic update that downloaded the latest bios for Asus vivobook s531fl, the computer prompt me to restart to install the latest updates.

After restarting, the computer installed the latest BIOS firmware and restarted it again automatically.

When the computer restarts again and I select windows, the computer ran to an error screen saying that windows 10 insider ran to a problem and it will restart automatically. Since I use Ubuntu as my primary OS, I tried to log in to the Ubuntu from the grub menu which shows this error.

```
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/405284ra-02g6-13c8-3747-0138t7t8f285 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.0 (Ubuntu 1:1.10.3-7ubuntu1.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: @singrium: Why do you "correct" correct english? "Does anybody know" is correct but your correction isn't.

Comment: @SerafimDahl, sorry, I didn't see 'Does' in the beginning.. :/ I thought it was "anybody knows ....".
I will edit that.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for correcting the syntax and grammatical issues. Actually I was typing from my mobile without autocorrection which results in these types of mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couple of hours of searching, I found the solution to my problem. Answering the question myself so that whoever facing this issue finds a solution quickly.

With the BIOS being updated by windows updates, the settings of my BIOS had been restored the factory default settings. Since I had dual-booted the Ubuntu and Windows 10 both in a SSD drive, the SATA operation had to be changed from RAID to AHCI in the BIOS menu.

- Go to your BIOS menu.
- In the "Advanced" tab, go to the "SATA Configuration"
- Select "AHCI" instead of "Intel RST Premium With Intel Optane System Acceleration"
- Save Changes and Exit

If you boot into windows, the system should then repair startup automatically and start normally. Ubuntu was also working for me like previously.